# RegEx Not working in Ruby!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am using the following regex

```
html.scan(Regexp.new(/Name:<\/td>(.*?)<\/td>/s))
```

to match the name [ `Burkhart, Peterson &amp; Company` ] in this

```
<td class="generalinfo_left" align="right">Name:</td>
<td class="generalinfo_right">Burkhart, Peterson &amp; Company</td>
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally parsing (X)HTML using Regular Expressions is bad practice. Ruby has the fantastic [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) Library which uses libxml2 for parsing XHTML efficiently.

Which that being said, your `.` does not match newlines. Use the `m` modifier for your regexp which tells the `.` to match new lines. Or the Regexp::MULTILINE constant. Documented [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html#M001198)

Your regular expression is also capturing the HTML before the text you require.

Using nokogiri and XPath would mean you could grab the content of this table cell by referring to its CSS class. Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML DATA.read

p doc.at("td[@class='generalinfo_right']").text

__END__
<td class="generalinfo_left" align="right">Name:</td>
<td class="generalinfo_right">Burkhart, Peterson &amp; Company</td>
```

Which will return `"Burkhart, Peterson & Company"`

Comment: How to use `Regexp::MULTILINE` Constant? cant understand properly from documentation

Comment: Regexp.new(/foo bar/, Regexp::MULTILINE)

Answer (score 2):

`/m` makes the dot match newlines

Comment: In non-Ruby regexes it works here (no Ruby available a.t.m.). Are you sure the string is as you claim it to be?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use /m for multiline mode:

`str.scan(/Name:</td>(.*?)</td>/m)`

Answer (score 0):

`html.scan(Regexp.new(/Name:<\/td>(.*?)<\/td>/s))` doesn't match the new line characters; even if it would match those characters, the `(.*?)` part would grab everything after `</td>`, including `<td class="generalinfo_right">`.

To make the regular expression more generic, and allow to match the exact text you want, you should change the code to

```
html.scan(Regexp.new(/Name:<\/td><td[^>]*>(.*?)<\/td>/s))
```

The regular expression could be better written, though.

I would also not suggest to parse HTML/XHTML content with regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that all the answers suggesting you add /m or Regexp::MULTILINE are correct by going to rubular.com.

I also verified the solution in console, and also modifed the regex so that it would return only the name instead of all the extra junk.

```
    Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.8)
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > html = '<td class="generalinfo_left" align="right">Name:</td>
ree-1.8.7-2010.02'> <td class="generalinfo_right">Burkhart, Peterson &amp; Company</td>
ree-1.8.7-2010.02'> '
 => "<td class="generalinfo_left" align="right">Name:</td>\n<td class="generalinfo_right">Burkhart, Peterson &amp; Company</td>\n" 
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > html.scan(Regexp.new(/Name:<\/td>(.*?)<\/td>/m))
 => [["\n<td class="generalinfo_right">Burkhart, Peterson &amp; Company"]] 
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > html.scan(Regexp.new(/Name:<\/td>.*<td[^>]*>(.*?)<\/td>/m))
 => [["Burkhart, Peterson &amp; Company"]] 
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 >
```